# Websockets and cookies in Android

Tags: java, android, cookies, websocket, autobahn

I am developing an Android application and I need a Websockets framework that allows me to send cookies in the first connection of the Websocket(not in each message).

I've tried [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/android/) and [Java-WebSocket](http://java-websocket.org/) but they are not sending my cookies and they got no cookies support. What can I do? I don't think a WebView is a good solution for my app, since I need a service in the background always sending some messages to the Websocket.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to send cookies via http headers by Java-WebSocket's `WebSocketClient` class using `WebSocketClient( URI serverUri , Draft protocolDraft , Map<String,String> httpHeaders , int connectTimeout)` constructor?

Comment: That what's exactly what I wanted! I don't know why I didn't find it in the API docs and I couldn't find it on the web. Thank you man!

Comment: Hi @SashaSalauyou 
I am using Autobahn library for websocket in Android application. 
Can you please tell how to send cookies using the autobahn library.

Comment: @HarishVats One of the overloads of the connect method of autobahn allows you to pass a list of headers, see: https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-android/blob/8f72ede640c6fccb6009a0bbe4d9184b4219d3c0/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketConnection.java#L220