# Open WebSocket connection with authentication cookie

Tags: java, android, cookies, header, websocket

I have the same issue as [Websockets and cookies in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692763/websockets-and-cookies-in-android), and I have been trying to solve it as the first comment suggested,

> WebSocketClient( URI serverUri , Draft protocolDraft , Map httpHeaders , int connectTimeout)

using [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), as well as looking at many other APIs such as Jetty and [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync). But despite this I am unable to open up a websocket connection.

I have an [Apache http cookie](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/package-summary.html), and need this to authenticate myself to the server with a WebSocket. What is the correct way of translating a cookie into a httpHeader, or is there any neat way to simply add the entire cookie in the authentication when connection to a websocket? Maybe I am just missing the obvious..

Apologies for possible misuses of terms, but I hope you get the general idea.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I actually managed to solve it, and it turned out that it was not the cookie that was the actual issue, but rather that the websocket is not initialized with a valid sslcontext. This was solved rather easily by:

```
WebSocketOrderClient webSocketOrderClient = new WebSocketOrderClient(uri, new Draft_17(), cmap, TIMEOUT);
SSLContext sslContext = null;
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
sslContext.init( null, null, null ); // will use java's default key and trust store which is sufficient unless you deal with self-signed certificates

webSocketOrderClient.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(sslContext));
webSocketOrderClient.connectBlocking();
```

with WebSocketOrderClient:

```
private class WebSocketOrderClient extends WebSocketClient {
    public WebSocketOrderClient( URI serverUri, Draft draft, Map<String, String> headers, int timeout) {
        super( serverUri, draft, headers, timeout );
    }
    @Override
    public void onOpen( ServerHandshake handshakedata ) {
        Log.w("connected", "true");
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage( String message ) {
        Log.w( "got: ", message );
    }
    @Override
    public void onClose( int code, String reason, boolean remote ) {
        Log.w( "Disconnected", ""+code  );
    }
    @Override
    public void onError( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who might run into this problem in the future.